# GridView is scrolling back to top after row selection

Tags: asp.net, gridview, state

I've got one long GridView control on ma website. It allows row selection. The problem is, when I scroll down this GridView and select some of the bottom rows the selection occurs, but whole GridView is scrolling back to top. Does enyone know how to avoid this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If it's happening during a postback, then in your <%@ Page %> directive you can add the following:

```
MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true"
```

This was added in .NET 2.0, and adds some JavaScript to the page to ensure that the page scrolls back down to the control that caused the postback.

Works a treat.

Answer (score 4):

I've found another solution. If you have GridView inside scrollable div container I recommend this: [Maintain Scroll Position of DIV](http://michaelsync.net/2006/06/30/maintain-scroll-position-of-div-using-javascript-aspnet-20)

Answer (score 2):

Is it reloading the whole page after selecting the rows ? If so, try to put the GridView in an UpdatePanel, so that the event is sent to the server without actually reloading the whole page.