# Is FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex property in GridView Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I've got one long GridView control on ma website. It allows row selection. The problem is, when I scroll down this GridView and select some of the bottom rows the selection occurs, but whole GridView is scrolling back to top.

I refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/474526/gridview-is-scrolling-back-to-top-after-row-selection) for resolving my problem but not able to find any property into GridView control. I also search on [msdn Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.aspx) .

Please guide me where is this property and how can resolve my issue.Base on below checkbox event I select the row. After check the checkbox  enable to delete and edit button.

```
 protected void ChkChanged_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        int count = 0;
        foreach (GridViewRow gr in grdProducts.Rows)
        {

            CheckBox chkGrd = ((CheckBox)gr.FindControl("CheckBox2"));
            ImageButton editbutton = gr.FindControl("btnEdit") as ImageButton;
            ImageButton deleteButton = gr.FindControl("btnDeleted") as ImageButton;
            if (chkGrd.Checked)
            {
                count++;
                editbutton.Visible = true;
                deleteButton.Visible = true;                

                if (count > 1)
                    break;

            }
            else
            {
                editbutton.Visible = false;
                deleteButton.Visible = false;

            }
        }


        if (count > 1)
        {
            foreach (GridViewRow gr in grdProducts.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox chkGrd = ((CheckBox)gr.FindControl("CheckBox2"));
                ImageButton editbutton = gr.FindControl("btnEdit") as ImageButton;
                ImageButton deleteButton = gr.FindControl("btnDeleted") as ImageButton;
                if (chkGrd.Checked)
                {
                    editbutton.Visible = false;
                    deleteButton.Visible = false;
                }
            }

            DeleteAll.Enabled = true;
        }


    }
```

Comment: put gridview in update panel and try.

Comment: @sajanyamaha: I tried but it's move on top when I select the row into gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give your '`row selection`' code,is it posting back the entire page,If so, try to put the GridView in an `UpdatePanel`, so that the event is sent to the server without actually reloading the whole page.

Comment: Base on checkbox selection my row is select.

Comment: i guess the autoPostBack of checkbox is "True",try "False"

Comment: base on checkbox event I need to perform some operation here I put my checkbox checked event code.

Answer (score 0):

Where are the scrollbars - to the page or to the grid-view? If possible, get rid of scrollbars to the grid-view and get scroll bars at the page level. In such case, you can use [MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.maintainscrollpositiononpostback.aspx) which is a page property and it maintains page' scroll position on the post-back.

If your layout does not allow you to have scroll-bars at the page then I will suggest that you use a container div to the grid-view and have scroll-bars at the div level (instead of table i.e. grid-view) level. Now, you can have some JS code that can record the scroll position into the hidden field before page gets submitted and then same can use used after post-back to restore the position back. See this link where it uses such a trick : http://michaelsync.net/2006/06/30/maintain-scroll-position-of-div-using-javascript-aspnet-20

Comment: Scrolling on div. I set the  MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback = true . but it's only work for Page. It's not work on gridview which is inside the DIV.

Comment: @SaroopTrivedi, see the other link (the last sentence) - that answers how to maintain scroll position for the div.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer .

In GridViewRow have Focus() method.

```
 gr.Focus();
```

It's 95% set the position in your gridview selected Row.